# Telnet response to CAPABILITY differs from actual response

Tags: windows, imap, telnet

I have a problem on **one** of my machines.
I connect to some IMAP server and do ". CAPABILITY" request:

```
* OK IMAP4 ready
. CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 UIDPLUS
. OK completed
```

But if I inspect response in Wireshark I get
`* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED` which is the expected result.
And it works just fine on other machines.
What can be wrong?

Actually I have similar problem with openssl connection on that machine: `Didn't find STARTTLS in server response, trying anyway...`, but I think it has the same root cause.

Comment: Question is why do I have incorrect response in telnet. I do exactly what I described: connect, than send ". CAPABILITY"

Comment: I stated explictly that this is openssl problem. I just think that it has the same root cause: whatever method openssl uses to get server capabilities, it doesn't return STARTTLS capability either,
So somebody might encounter similar problem not with telnet itself, but with openssl or other tools.

P.S. Original commenter deleted their posts, but I keep my answers for clarity.

Comment: Different configuration on the plaintext vs the SSL port?

Comment: Where do you run wireshark? There might be a meddling firewall involved, one that does something stupid to your TCP connection when it sees the word 'starttls'. That firewall might even run on the host where you run telnet, so the correct packets arrive but the wrong data is delivered to the user-level process.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I didn't have enough time to dig deep into the problem. After some fiddling with updates, software reinstallation, changing IPs and so on I gave up, formatted C and made clean Windows installation.
It helped, as it usually is with such weird behaviors.